# Is this an application that is executable? / Executing a javascript program

Tags: javascript, html, github, underscore.js

I'm struggling a little bit here - Is this github repo an application that is executable, and if so how would I execute it (aka is this a program that can be executed in the browswer or in jsfiddle)?

https://github.com/emiidee/underbar

Or is it just code placed in a github repo?

There's an HTML file, CSS and some javascript, and I'm assuming the underscore js library is imported, but if anyone could offer me a shove in the right direction with regards on how to get this baby up and running, it would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

No, it's HTML and JavaScript source, not an executable.  If you clone the repo to your local environment you'll be able to load it up in your browser and take a look.  Eg from your local WWW root:

`git clone https://github.com/emiidee/underbar.git underbar`

Then if you load `http://<yourlocalwebserver>/underbar` you'll see the results.